# Angular 5 material autocomplete with firestore data

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material2, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

i am facing error in slice operation on observable of type any
receiving from firestore.
i am trying to make an angular material autocomplete with firestore data.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

customerCtrl: FormControl;
filteredCustomer: Observable<any[]>;
customers_coll: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
customers: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore,private _data: DataService) {
console.log("home");
this.customerCtrl = new FormControl();
this.customers_coll = 
this.afs.collection('USERS').doc(this._data.phone).collection("CUSTOMERS");
this.customers = this.customers_coll.valueChanges();

}

ngOnInit() {

this.filteredCustomer = this.customerCtrl.valueChanges
.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(customer => customer ? this.filterCustomer(customer) : 
  this.customers.slice())
  );
  }

  filterCustomer(name: string) {
  return this.customers.filter(customer =>
    customer.NAME.toLowerCase().indexOf(NAME.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }
  }
```

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: @Edric Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.eval

Comment: I would remove the startsWith, if that is your error, then if that is the problem I’d say use withlatestfrom